# How to erase a line in terminal on any keypress with readline in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, readline

I am using the [Haskell bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/readline-1.0.3.0) to `readline` library for reading input from the user.

What I want to achieve is to offer a prefilled value that can be submitted by just hitting the return key, but if the user starts typing, I would like to erase the prefilled text automatically. (So that user does not have to care about erasing prefilled value.)

I think it could be done by using the `rl_getc_function` hook. However, the Haskell bindings do not expose this function.

Is there some way how to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Maybe using `rl_insert_text` aka `insertText` you can get the wanted effect?

Comment: @chi that function can be used to prefill the text, but I don't know how to use it to erase the text on any key press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out a way to do it, but it is not nice and feels like a bit of a hack.

It works by rebinding all keys to a custom function that first erases the line, then resets all these handlers to actually insert the character again. In order not to lose the triggering keypress it is pushed back to input.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- create a copy of current keymap
    keymap <- getKeymap >>= copyKeymap
    -- bind (hopefully all) regular keys to a helper function
    forM_ (map toEnum [32..256]) $ \key ->
        bindKey key $ \ _ _ -> do
            -- delete all text on line
            getEnd >>= deleteText 0
            -- set cursor to start of line
            setPoint 0
            redisplay
            -- reset keymap to the original one
            setKeymap keymap
            -- push pressed key back to input
            setPendingInput key
            return 0
    setStartupHook (Just $ insertText "prefilled text")
    readline "prompt> "
```

The major pain point of this is determining which keys to rebind. I used a scientific method of trial and error: the lower bound is space (anything less than that is non-printable, may have some special function and I don't want to mess with it). The upper bound is set to 256 – anything more resulted in segfault, using lesser number left the function not working on some unicode input.

Even with this range, it might not work if the user starts typing something in  [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters). It definitely does not work correctly if the user types something by using a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key).